# how can I reformat sequences (several lines) in a fasta file to single line?

Tags: bash, sed, fasta

Input "file.fasta" (**note**, this is a sample .... in fasta file, the sequences may have more than three lines)

```
>chr1:117223140-117223856 TAG:GTGGG
GTGGgggggcgCATAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGAGtt
aGTAGTATCGAATCGCACGACTGACAGCTCAGCATCAGCGACGACTAGTG
GTGGGCGACGACAgCGATATA
>chr2:117223140-117223856 TAG:GGGCT
ACGAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCagCCGATCGACGACTCAAGTACGATACGCGaa
cCCCCCGACGACGACTCACGA
```

Expected output

```
>chr1:117223140-117223856 TAG:GTGGG
GTGGgggggcgCATAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGAGttaGTAGTATCGAATCGCACGACTGACAGCTCAGCATCAGCGACGACTAGTGGTGGGCGACGACAgCGATATA
>chr2:117223140-117223856 TAG:GGGCT
ACGAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCagCCGATCGACGACTCAAGTACGATACGCGaacCCCCCGACGACGACTCACGA
```

my effort: `sed` command

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\([actgACGT]\)\n\([actgACGT]\)/\1\2/g' file.fasta
```

my wrong output:

```
>chr1:117223140-117223856 TAG:GTGGGGTGGgggggcgCATAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGAGttaGTAGTATCGAATCGCACGACTGACAGCTCAGCATCAGCGACGACTAGTGGTGGGCGACGACAgCGATATA
>chr2:117223140-117223856 TAG:GGGCTACGAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCagCCGATCGACGACTCAAGTACGATACGCGaacCCCCCGACGACGACTCACGA
```

The regular expression for header (lines whose first letter is ">") is `"^>.*$"`, but I do not know how to include in `sed` command

thanks in advance

Comment: @tripleee you are right is duplicated, I had not seen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;N;/>/!s/\n//;ta;P;D' file
```

Look at two lines and if either does not contains a `>` delete the newline between them and repeat. If either of the lines does contain a `>` then print and delete the first of them and then repeat.

Comment: I will study `sed`, I still have much to learn ..... thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '/^>/ {print (NR>1?"\n":"")$0;; next} {printf "%s",$0;} END{print "";}' file.fasta 
>chr1:117223140-117223856 TAG:GTGGG
GTGGgggggcgCATAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGAGttaGTAGTATCGAATCGCACGACTGACAGCTCAGCATCAGCGACGACTAGTGGTGGGCGACGACAgCGATATA
>chr2:117223140-117223856 TAG:GGGCT
ACGAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCagCCGATCGACGACTCAAGTACGATACGCGaacCCCCCGACGACGACTCACGA
```

#### How it works

- `/^>/ {print (NR>1?"\n":"")$0;; next}`

  If the line starts with `>`, that is if the regex `/^>/` is true, then print the line.  If this is not the first line, that is if `NR>1`, then print a newline character ahead of the line.  Then, skip the rest of the commands and jump to start over on the `next` line.
- `printf "%s",$0;`

  For all other lines, print them without a trailing newline.
- `END{print "";}`

  After we have reached the end of the file, print one last newline character.